# How to set size of a dialog box with knockout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, dialog

I have this dialog where I want to set the size. I thought this should be so simple but I can´t get it to work. Below I have put in an option to the bindingHandler: "minWidth: 600", but the dialog remains the default size. How can I change this?

```
<div id="dialog-sequence" class="dialog-acc" data-bind="dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': $root.selectedProject().title }, dialogVisible: $root.isSequenceDialogOpen, minWidth: 600">
    <div id="tb-accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion: { },template: { name: 'sequence-template', foreach: $root.TextbatchesPure }"></div>
</div>
```

where my template is:

```
<script type="text/html" id="sequence-template" >
    <div class="group" data-bind="attr: {'id': textbatchID}">
        <div class="accordion-header ui-widget-header">
             <h3><span data-bind="text: title"></span>  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" style="float:right; margin:6px 10px 0px 50px;"></span></h3>
         </div>
     </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Found the solution: I had to move "minWidth: 600" inside the brackets. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width something like this

```
app.showMessage("Message", "Title", ["Close"], true, { style:  { width: "600px"} });
```